# Does declaring a constructor '= default' in a header file break the ODR

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

If I define the destructor (or any autogenerated constructor) as default like this:

```
struct A { 
   ~A() = default;
};
```

And then include this in several translation units, does this break the ODR? Can someone walk me through the steps at on the [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) page? Because i am struggling to understand if the compiler generated destructor will be inline or some other effect to prevent it from breaking the ODR.

Comment: All member functions that are defaulted within a class definition are implicitly inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ODR violation. Member functions are implicitly inline if they are defined, defaulted or deleted inside a class definition.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

> The implicitly-generated member functions and any member function
> declared as defaulted on its first declaration are inline just like
> any other function defined inside a class definition.

```
// header file

// OK, implicit inline
struct A  {
    ~A() {}
};
```

```
// header file

// OK, implicit inline
struct A  {
    ~A() = default;
};
```

```
// header file

struct A  {
    ~A();
};


// NOT ok, ODR violation when header is included in more than 1 TU
A::~A() {};
```

```
// header file

struct A  {
    ~A();
};


// NOT ok, ODR violation when header is included in more than 1 TU
A::~A() = default;
```

Comment: Uggh, that was not where i expected to find the answer. Seems like there should be a link to that from the constructor page.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox maybe. The standard is very interconnected. I know this from experience.